# How to get started with stripe payments with firebase and iOS?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm trying to get started with stripe to build out a Patreon like app. I've done a lot of searching and have even started with [these docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide#return_url) from Stripe. Unfortunately, I am encountering many problems, probably as a result of a faulty integration.

What I am using:

- I am using Firebase database.
- Express accounts in stripe
- iOS

What I am trying to achieve:

- User1 can create a subscription of his chosen price.
- User2 can join/pay the subscription.
- User1 gets 70% of his money made from the subscription, and I the developer get remainder.

What I have done so far:

- Created a Stripe account and set it up at a very base level.
- created an Xcode project and included [code up until step 2.3](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide#return_url)
- I have setup firebase functions at a base level, and have some code in there from steps up to 2.3 in link above.

*What I would like is to have a clear starting point, and path to follow.*
**How do I get started in achieveing this goal?**

Comment: This is a really broad question.  You need to design your application, and then implement the design.  There won't be a checklist for this.  If you have specific questions as you run into issues, those can be addressed, but this is too broad an ask to be able to help.

Comment: @floatingLomas Surly Stripe users are not assumed to know everything?? To instantly know what to implement and where...

Answer (score 1):

Just commenting on the Stripe portion -- what you can do is have a page where your content creators (i.e. User1) can create a Product. Each Product must be tied to a Price:

On another page, retrieve all active Products so content receivers (i.e. User2) can subscribe to it.

Full details can be found at https://stripe.com/docs/billing/prices-guide.

For the revenue splitting, Stripe doesn't seem to support this. Your only option is to do a payout to your business bank account, then further disburse the 70% to your content creators. For this, you must be able to match payment records on Stripe to your database, e.g. design your database in such a way it can answer the SQL query "what is the total amount paid to this particular content creator within a given time period?".

Comment: I consistently have errors associated with the await command. I am using firebase functions with javascript.